# When staking SOL on-chain... questions about Stake Accounts

Tags: staking

This is a question regarding my **stake** account, not my regular SOL wallet.

I am aware that rewards that are collected automatically and re-staked. However, my question has to do with how that happens. The transaction history on my **stake** account is seemingly showing transactions every epoch that are signed by **someone else** on **my** stake account and that has me concerned about security: am I doing this right?

If you're staking SOL on-chain, are you noticing that someone else is making transactions on your account? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more information, for example, a sample transaction involving your stake account. If your stake account has a different staking authority than your wallet, then someone else can make changes to the stake account, without taking any funds out. Otherwise, are you sure that this stake account is owned by you? Make sure that the withdrawal authority is your address.

Answer (score 2):

Staking rewards will be distributed (every epoch) by the provider you are staking too. So this all is correct and nothing to worry about.

The fact that you are seeing transactions associated with your "stake account", but are not signed by you is totally okay and normal. Your account (either your stake account or regular account) only has to sign the transaction if your balance is reduced.

This is all because of how Solana processes transactions.

#### How Solana processes transactions

Every Solana transaction requires a complete list of every address that is used in the transaction. Both reading and writing data to those account's on chain. No matter who the actual signer is.

For every transaction, any account that is reducing their token balance must sign the transaction (or a different account that has authority over it). But any account that is gaining tokens does not have to sign the transaction.

For example with staking rewards, when the staking payout is ready to be sent to your staking account:

- the staking provider will sign the transaction (since they are the one sending the tokens)
- they will list your stake account address as the receiver of those funds (your account does not need to sign since your are not sending tokens, only receiving)
- the transaction will also list some other assorted program addresses (like the system program, etc)

If you look at a transaction on a Solana block explorer, you will see the complete list of every address that was "associated" with the transaction (e.g. those reads or write), but normally only one signer.

Answer (score 1):

If transaction is signed by `GZctHpWXmsZC1YHACTGGcHhYxjdRqQvTpYkb9LMvxDib` it's the distribution of MEV rewards from Jito.

From: https://jito-foundation.gitbook.io/mev/jito-solana/command-line-arguments

> --merkle-root-upload-authority Authority that uploads MEV airdrop merkle roots to the validator's MEV "piggy bank". This authority automates the airdrop and claim process, so stakers don't need to manually claim rewards. if you set it to Jito - GZctHpWXmsZC1YHACTGGcHhYxjdRqQvTpYkb9LMvxDib, Jito will run the airdrop and claim process for you.